# Query don’t work [Node.js/GraphQL]

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, graphql

I tried to do some requests to my database : 
[request graphql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xosL5.png)

With the code :

```
.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(( req ) => {
let sess = req.session;
sess.ctx = {};

return {
    schema    : PublicSchema,
    pretty    : true,
    graphiql  : true,
    rootValue : {
      schema : 'public'
    },
    context   : sess.ctx
  };
})
)
```

And as you can see that worked.
But when I try to do that with NodeJS, the request don't work, here is the code :

```
.get('/zob', function(req, res){
    let sess = req.session;
    sess.ctx = {};
    var { graphql } = require('graphql');
    var query = 'mutation{getToken(email:"###", password:"##"){token}}';
    graphql(PublicSchema, query, sess.ctx).then((response) => {
        console.log("hey");
        console.log(response);
    });
})
```

(I put the real email and password in my code)
And the console respond :
`"{ data: { getToken: { token: null } }"` with error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined."
```

GetToken function return Null.

So, i did the same thing on GraphiQL and nodeJS but with NodeJS the query don't work. Why ???

Can you help me ?
Thanks!